# Does hair fall first from the top of head because of reduced blood supply due to lack of movement?

Tags: physiology, hair

In [this very quackery-like video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-0_8Y-wOwPI&list=PLjbZaBQyopEbSVbW7o5WGvlv9CG0SIF8A), it's claimed that hair loss occurs first from the top of the head rather than the side because the latter moves when chewing or doing other facial movements. This would increase the blood supply in the lateral part of head, while the unmoving top receives a lesser supply of blood.

Is this relation between facial movement, blood supply and hair loss supported by any scientific evidence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hair falls from the top of head first because the follicles there are more androgen-sensitive.

> Within the distribution of hair over the scalp, androgen-sensitive hair follicles are on top and androgen-insensitive follicles are on the sides and back...the androgen-sensitive follicles are transformed into vellus follicles

Quoting from [Understanding Pathophysiology](https://books.google.com/books?id=vyGKCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA1078&dq=top%20head%20androgen%20sensitive&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiC4ovzirfLAhVO52MKHRe0DfoQ6AEITDAG#v=onepage&q=top%20head%20androgen%20sensitive&f=false) at page 1078.

Also, from [Aging Men's Health: A Case-based Approach](https://books.google.com/books?id=tDxsAAAAMAAJ&q=the%20androgen%20sensitive%20follicles%20are%20transformed%20into%20vellus&dq=the%20androgen%20sensitive%20follicles%20are%20transformed%20into%20vellus&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHudiUzLjLAhUJzGMKHbFlDQcQ6AEIUDAH), page 88:

> androgens lead to male pattern baldness or androgenetic alopecia (AGA) by inhibiting terminal hair follicles and transforming them into vellus hair

Comment: Why are they androgen sensitive, though? Is there a way to prove that it is not a result of differential blood supply?

Comment: "Why are they androgen sensitive, though?" -- Developmental patterns. It's like why you have hands at the ends of your arms rather than feet or noses or something. It's also why people have dark hair in their pubic areas but vellus hair elsewhere. "Is there a way to prove that it is not a result of differential blood supply?" -- sure ... change the blood supply and measure the androgen uptake.

Comment: Is there any research about how and why this specific developmental pattern arise?